# Subtracting two different time formats in swift

Tags: ios, swift, time

```
           NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            // Get data as string
            if let object = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject] {
                let rows = object["rows"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let elements = rows.first!["elements"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let duration = elements.first!["duration"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                let durationText = duration["text"] as! String
                print("duration for NY : \(durationText)")
            }

        }).resume()

   @IBAction func onDateChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle


    let timeinterval = NSTimeInterval.abs(17 * 60) // ====================================== EDIT TO INCORPORATE TRAVEL TIME OF TWO DISTANCES =====================
    let newDate = datePicker.date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-timeinterval)
    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate)

    print("\(strDate) is the date on the datePicker @willcohen")
```

Hello, I need to subtract the string, durationText, from the newDate. So for example, the duration text would be something like 1hr 12min and the new date would be something like 8:40 PM. How would I go about subtracting the 1hr 12min from 8:40 PM? Any suggestions would

Edit:

```
           NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            // Get data as string
            if let object = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject] {
                let rows = object["rows"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let elements = rows.first!["elements"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                let duration = elements.first!["duration"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                let durationText = duration["text"] as! String
                print("duration for NY : \(durationText)")

                let numberStrings = durationText.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
                    NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).filter
                    { $0.characters.count > 0 }

                let hours:Double = Double(numberStrings[0])!
                let minutes:Double = Double(numberStrings[1])!

                self.durationTime = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60)
                print("\(self.durationTime) is the duration time")

                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
                self.newDate = self.datePicker.date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(self.durationTime)

                let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.newDate)
                print("\(strDate) is the time you should leave at @willcohen")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only real part of the problem left for you is parsing a string like "1hr 12min" into a `NSTimeInterval` (`Double`). After that, you can use `dateByAddingTimeInterval` as in your sample code. You will need to be careful that these input strings such as "1hr 12min" are in a consistent format so you can parse them, but something like this could work for the given input:

Edit: since it seems you want "x minutes" to also be a possible input, I adjusted the code below:

```
//split the string by all non-number characters (leaving just the numbers)
let numberStrings = durationText.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
        NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).filter 
        { $0.characters.count > 0 }

//get the individual components
let hours:Double
let minutes:Double
if numberStrings.count == 1 {
    hours = 0
    minutes = Double(numberStrings[0])
}
else {
    hours = Double(numberStrings[0])
    minutes = Double(numberStrings[1])
}

//make the NSTimeInterval
let duration:NSTimeInterval = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60)
```

Like I mentioned above, this relies on your durationTexts being in that format (`[number]hr [number]min`). You'll need to adjust this code if your strings come in formats that, for instance, contain seconds, or decimal values.

Comment: This is giving me an error, saying that on the `let hours` and `let minutes` statements, that the `value of type "String" has no member of doubleValue`

Comment: Hmm, it is giving me another error in the `let minutes` statement because it said that it was unwrapping a nil value, because I had to change it to `let minutes: Double = Double(numberStrings[1])!`

Comment: Ah yes, you'll need to do that. Sorry, I didn't have xCode in front of me until now. The only remaining problem is `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` will give you an entry between *every* non-number, including blank strings for, for instance, the components between "h" and "r". So you need to filter blank strings (see my edit above). This one worked for me, I promise!

Comment: So, is does this come out to be in seconds, or minutes?

Comment: Never mind, I got it, thank you so much for continuing to answer the questions I had1

Comment: Seconds, which is the unit for `NSTimeInterval.` Glad to help! Please accept the answer when you get the chance

Comment: actually, I am still getting an error strangely on the `let minutes` statement and the error is `Thread 27: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: what is the `durationText`?

Comment: I just edited my original post to paste the code that I edited.

Comment: What happens when you try to `print(durationText)`?

Comment: print(durationText) returns in the console 1 minute

Comment: This is what I was mentioning above: the way of parsing the code above requires 2 numbers; one for hours and one for minutes. So you could write some additional logic to handle this type of string (hint: `if numberStrings.count == 1 { ... }`), or you could change the JSON data to be in the same format (ie. `0 hours 1 minute`).

Comment: Hmm.. I tried adding                    `if numberStrings.count == 1 {
                        hours = 0.0
                    }` after the hours and minutes let statements ?(changed let hours to var hours), but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Because you're still trying to assign minutes to numberStrings[1], which doesn't exist. See my edit.

Comment: actually, the code that you edited does not give me any errors, however it is always giving me that the minutes = 1 and the hours is eqal to 0

Comment: You need to try to work through it. Print out your input so you know what it should give you, and run through the code